# How to make the generated HTML file auto-indent in WebStorm 10

Tags: html, pug, webstorm, auto-indent

I'm using WebStorm 10 with Jade. The generated HTML is not auto-indent, for e.g:

**index.jade:**

```
extends layout
    block content
        h1= title
        p Welcome to #{title}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"></head><body><h1></h1><p>Welcome to </p></body></html>
```

Is there a way to auto-indent the generated HTML ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> on Windows and Linux

<kbd>Option + Command + L</kbd> on Mac OS X

See [Reformatting Source Code](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/reformatting-source-code.html)

**Updated**

If you set the `$FileName$ --pretty` in **Arguments:** the output should be nicely formatted.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: But you have to do that every time you change the jade file. How to auto-align, auto-indent the HTML file whenever the jade file changed ?

Comment: I don't understand what your use case is. Can you provide some detail?

Comment: So I have File Watcher setup for Jade, so for every line of code changed, it will re-generate the HTML file. But the generated HTML file is in a single line format. Can I force WebStorm File Watcher to generate the HTML in indented style ?

Comment: Which Jade engine are you using? Can you post a screen shot of your watcher settings. Try editing your watcher and adding `$FileName$ --pretty` to your arguments field.

Comment: ok I must be a total dumb to not trying: `jade --help`. I was thinking it must be a WebStorm feature, turns out it is Jade option

Comment: Perfect. Setting: $FileName$ --pretty, solved my problem. Thank you so much.